# How to use single word as JSON data in android?

Tags: android, json

I am trying to extract the JSON data which is just a single word. I have used JSON Array when it was a long list of a set of data but this time it just a word like - **done** or **failed**.

My Code is -

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
//JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("contacted");
loggingTest = jsonObject.getString("??"); // what to put here (??) as
//there is just a single word.
```

It may be very easy to get it but I feels I am missing something. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: post Json response which you want to extract from ??

Comment: the URL just gives a word like - done that's it not even " or : { nothing.

Answer (score 0):

> URL just gives a word like - done that's it not even " or : { nothing

Then simply use the `String` variable `s` , don't convert it into json

plus you can put this `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);` in `try-catch` to recognize that respose is simply a valid json or not , if not it will throw an exception

```
try{
    // exception will be thrown in case of invalid json
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s); 
 }
  catch(JSONException e){ 
  // s containing a single word so use it as it is 
}
```